# C# Winforms DataGridViewTextBoxCell with scrolling-ticker text

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ticker

I'm looking to create a custom DataGridViewTextBoxCell who's text will slowly move from right-to-left on a timer if the text is too large to fit in the cell.

So a standard ticker, except in a DataGridView cell.

I've played around with overriding the DataGridViewTextBoxCell Paint() method but can't seem to find any way of accomplishing this.

Is this possible or am I wasting my time?

I've tried creating a timer and adjusting the "formattedValue" and repainting but this results in scrolling by individual letters and looks choppy. I don't see any way to partially draw a character based on the existing Paint() method.

Comment: You should probably post what you have written for this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.